# Hive: how to collect edges in a connected component in a graph using hive query

Tags: graph, hive

I have an undirected graph as below

```
+---------------------------+
|  id  |  node_1  |  node_2 | 
+---------------------------+
| 111  |    n1    |   n2    |
| 111  |    n3    |   n4    |
| 111  |    n3    |   n5    |
| 111  |    n5    |   n4    |
+---------------------------+
```

and try to cluster connected vertices in an array like

```
+-------------------------------+
|  id  |  same_cluster         | 
+------------------------------+
| 111  |    ["n1", "n2"]       |
| 111  |    ["n3", "n4", "n5"] |
+------------------------------+
```

So basically store the connected component as arrays, but can't figure out a good logic to achieve this goal. Any suggestions are appreciated.